# Surely distilled water is the answer to a polluted planet

Tags: physical-chemistry

I have been researching a long time on best water to drink and find that there are so many sources of pollution from industry, farming, agriculture and so forth creating run off into our fresh water sources, even the treatment plants seem to add to the problem by adding chemicals.

Distillation separates the many compounds from the water through evaporation then condensing therefore leaving behind what we don’t need in water.

All our minerals are really found in food.
I feel it’s the safest way to keep us healthy as don’t want these dangerous compounds in my body.

Comment: Do you think your food is magically free from the same sources of pollution?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Distilled water can be very dangerous if  large quantities are taken ; causing electrolyte depletion. A friend ( Phd Chem Engineer) once drank distilled water  exclusively for a couple days to get a drunk-like "high".

Comment: I am even thinking that getting a drunk like feeling by distilled water is stressing the body more than ethanol. It is basically ionic imbalance and we, at least roughly, know that among other things ions are essential for moving muscles, the first of which we need is heart.

Answer (score 1):

The water which is distributed in the public is not polluted. It has been first filtrated through a layer of fine grains of activated wood charcoal that fixes most unwanted impurities. Then it is treated by gases like chlorine or ozone that eliminates unwanted substances or toxic bacteria that would have passed through the charcoal filter. Don't forget that bacteria in water are much more dangerous than chemical impurities.

Nobody wants dangerous compounds in the drinkable water. That is even the reason why Health officers are checking the quality of the water continuously, all over the world. In case of a contamination, they take steps to eliminate this drawback. They are paid for doing that.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that water purification to render it potable, as described in Maurice's answer, is much less costly per gallon than distillation.